# Prove that if matrix ABC invertible(A,B,C all n x n), then matrix B is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification, inverse

Is my proof correct? Can you find any errors?

Prove that if matrix $ABC$ invertible($A$,$B$,$C$ all $n$ x $n$), then matrix $B$ is invertible.

Part One:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two $n$ x $n$ matrices such that $XY$=$I$, if we right multiply boths sides by **b** $∈  ℝ ^n$ we obtain $X$($Y$**b**)=**b**. Thus the corresponding linear transformation $T(z)$=$X$**z** is onto and this is true IFF there is a pivot in every row which is true for an $n$ x $n$ matrix $X$ IFF $X$ is row equivalent to $I$ which is true IFF $X$ is invertible.

Part Two:
If $ABC$ is invertible then there exist an $n$ x $n$ matrix $D$ such that $ABCD=I$.

$ABCD=A(BCD)=I$

So, A is invertible and its inverse is $A^{-1}=BCD$ and so $BCD$ is invertible.

If $BCD$ is invertible then there exist an $n$ x $n$ matrix $E$ such that $BCDE=I$.

$BCDE=B(CDE)=I$ and so $B$ is invertible.

Comment: A question posted here should be understandable by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Yes, I think that that would work.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Another way to see that $A, B$ and $C$ must all be invertible is by noticing that $C$ must be surjective (else the $ABC$ can't be surjective), and by the same argument $B$ must be surjective and therefore $A$ must be surjective. But for $nxn$ matrices, surjective implies injective, so it is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix $ABC$ is invertible iff $\det(ABC) \neq 0$.

Therefore $\det(A)\det(B)\det(C) \ne 0$.

As a consequence $\det(B) \ne 0$

which is equivalent to say that $B$ is invertible ($A$ and $C$ as well...).

Comment: I appreciate the response. I am trying to do this without using determinants. I am more looking for solution verification rather than alternative proof. If you can give me feedback on my proof that would be great.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Another time, say in your text that you don't want a simpler proof...

Comment: I didn't tag my post with alternative proof. There is nothing in my post to suggest that I am searching for an alternative proof. So I don't know what you are talking about when you say "say in your text that you don't want a simpler proof." Seems ridiculous.

Comment: I beg your pardon ; probably, I shouldn't have done this remark. It's an habit for me, as a teacher, to look for different alternative solutions to a problem and "put them on the table" for my students...